# fork() doesn't execute child process code

Tags: c, process, fork

I am new to fork() and I'm trying to figure out how is it possible that the program, you see below, doesn't execute the code of the child process. Will you please help me understand what's going on?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int glob = 1;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
int local = 1;
int *dyn, pid;
char *myName = "parent";
dyn = (int *) malloc (sizeof(int));
*dyn = 1;

printf("Here it is how fork() works\n");
if ((pid = fork()) < 0)
{
    printf("Error.\n");
    exit(1);
}

printf("pid: %d", pid);
if (pid)
{
    sleep(1);
}
else
{
    glob = 2;
    local = 2;
    *dyn = 2;
    *myName = "child";
    printf("I'm the child!");
}
printf("[[ %s ]]\n glob=%d\n local=%d\n *dyn=%d\n", myName, glob, local, *dyn);
exit(0);
 }
```

Comment: What happens when you run this?  Actually, will this even compile?

Comment: How do you know the code in the child doesn't run ?

Comment: Yes, @OliCharlesworth it compiles just fine!

@nos, because this is the output:

Here it is how fork() works
pid: 2332[[ parent ]]
 glob=1
 local=1
 *dyn=1

Comment: @haunted: This code won't compile.  Please edit your question to include your *actual* code, along with the console output that you observe.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: I have just compiled it again. This is my actual code. I get a warning: 


main2.c: In function ‘main’:
main2.c:32:13: warning: assignment makes integer from pointer without a cast

but it compiles nonetheless.

Comment: @haunted: I consider compiling with warnings as "won't compile" (because I always have `-Werror` enabled).  Did you think to resolve the compiler warning/error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You child process is most likely killed by a segmentation fault:

```
*myName = "child";
```

is invalid as your compiler should have told you (if it didn't warn on that, please turn up the warnings/diagnostics level).

If you wanted to change `myName`, you'd need to use something like `strcpy`. But you can't do that on `myName` because it could point to read-only memory. You should initialize it with dynamic memory like you do for the `dyn` pointer.

If all you need is that `myName` points to a different string, you can use:

```
myName = "child";
```

Comment: Yes, it was that error!! So if my child process fails or gets a segmentation fault, won't I be warned? I know that there is something wrong just because I see the wrong results?

Comment: +1: good catch, but you can just change that to `myName = "child";` to fix that particular problem.

Comment: @haunted85: in these situations, use a debugger or valgrind, they'll tell you about this type of issue. Or simplify your code - remove the fork and just run the child branch.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth: you're absolutely right, I thought that it was "just a warning" and I didn't pay it that much attention. What I have learned today, a warning can mess up your life too!

Answer (score 1):

remove the '*' before myName.

```
myName = "child";
```